# combine regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have two regualar rexpressions I would like to combine into the one for performance games but unsure how to achieve. The first expression finds all the images in html, the second, finds all input buttons of type image.

1. `Regex.Matches(html, @"<img[^>]*?src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);`
2. `Regex.Matches(html, @"<input[^>]*?src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);`

How could I combine these?

Comment: Regex for html parsing is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've written it is a little ambiguous...but from what I can tell you want a list that contains both images and input buttons of type image. (not sure what u mean by input button of type image?

so you can put brackets and an or in between

ie.. (regex1|regex2)

depending how specific the contents of the tags is you could also have something like

```
<(?:img|input)[^>]*?src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>
```

Comment: Better make that: `(regex1)|(regex2)`

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using Html Agility Pack to parse html documents fastly and correctly:

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes I would prefer to go with this but due licence restrictions I cant.

Comment: @Niall: Its Ms public License not much different than GNU, so you can use and redistribute it. You can checkout details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424307/how-does-ms-pl-license-work